# Phonegap android youtube video stream

Tags: android, cordova, youtube

i have a problem with android and phonegap. I am finding out the best way to load an online video stream from youtube, my code is the below:

The video will not load, it displays a screen with the red youtube button but the video will never load on play...

your help is very much appreciated..

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using HTML5 video on Android, it is not supported by the operating system on Android 2.x devices.  Try this native plugin: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/VideoPlayer

Comment: Thank you ill try it and let you know...if i need to do the same for iPhone, what should i use? thank you